# Ajax GET request with a parameter Play Framework 2.5.X

Tags: ajax, playframework

I am using the play Framework 2.5.X and I'm trying to fetch some data from my controller using an AJAX call that executes on a button click. Here's the ajax code :

```
lastClickedWrench = $(this).attr('id');
uri = 'http://example.com/ontology#' + lastClickedWrench;
console.log("uri :" + uri);
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/roles/test:uri='+uri+'',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success', data);
    }
});
});
```

I am trying to send this Uri to the controller so I can execute a query, here's how the routes file look like :

```
GET     /roles/test:uri         app.controllers.RoleController.sendJson(uri : String)
```

And here's the controller it calls :

```
public Result sendJson(String uri)
{
    RoleDatabaseAccess access = new RoleJenaSparqlAccess();

    List<Skill> skills = access.getAssociatedSkills(uri);

    return ok(Json.toJson(skills));
}
```

The getAssociatedSkills method returns a List containing the result of a SPARQL query.

Anyway my main problem is that I can't seem to send this 'uri' in my GET request. I tried looking everywhere how to do it and all the results do it the way I just did in the routes but I still get an error :

```
jquery.min.js:4 
GET http://localhost:9000/roles/test:uri=http://wiserskills.com/ontology 404 (Not Found)
```

I would really appreciate any help/example on how to send an AJAX GET request with a parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out, my uri starts with an 'http' which messes up the AJAX call. Removing it fixes the problem.

Comment: It's because it starts with `http://`, not just `http`. You need to encode the URI before adding it to your request string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your URL isn't working because you're not marking the start of the parameters with ?

You have `/roles/test:uri=...`

You should have `/roles/test?uri=...`

Comment: I fixed the Ajax call but it's still the same problem.  Here's the error : 

roles/?uri=http://example.com/ontology#example_Role_28&_=1496321694753 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I really tried everything the official documentation is not helping, and the old stackoverflow answers do exaclty what I'm doing.